# On clicking hyperlink url gets changed in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am using ngRoute in my app and on clicking a hyperlink like this

```
<a href="/student/{{student.id}}">{{student.name}}</a>
```

the value gets changed to

```
http://localhost/student/1
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/bootstrap/aroute/index.html#/student/1
```

Route Provider code is

```
.when('/student/:id',{
    templateUrl : 'studentdetails.html',
    controller : 'MainController'
})
```

Why is that and how to fix it.

Comment: Shouldn't your href be <a href="#/student/{{student.id}}">{{student.name}}</a> ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/student/{{student.id}}">{{student.name}}</a>
```

when you start with / you rediret to root witch is localhost you remove /

you need start with #

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: Thnx for the solution.